# Enable clipboard Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, 16.04

I've got Ubuntu Server 16.04 recently installed and I don't know how to enable clipboard from the server to my computer and from my computer to the server because when I hit Ctrl+c or Ctrl+v it doesn't work from the server to the PC or from the PC to the server.

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running the server in a VM?

Answer (score 0):

Here it's my fix:

- Run in terminal: sudo apt-get install vnc4server
- Run in terminal: vnc4server (a message will appear in the terminal)
- Finally run: vncconfig and allow the clipboard.

For me it doesn't fix the clipboard between PC and server but it fix it between server and PC. It's something :)